# Is there a way to receive an optionally async closure in rust?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

So basically I have

```rust
TFn: Fn() -> TResult,
// the idea is to make this Future optiona
TResult: Future<Output = error::Result<usize>>,
```

I need to make a callback that is optionally async. It means that if function returns the future I want to make a `block_on` inside the function.

Is there any idiomatic way to do this without duplication?

Comment: Please give examples for how you expect usage would work.

Comment: you will have code duplication anyway, as your function would have to be async or not, and will need to await or not.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that without specialization.